# Selectively Bring Data to the DropDownList from Database and Bring All Other Data Sametime

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am saving city and town information to the user table while the user is registering. What I want to do is: When user goes to the user profile edit page, I want the city and the town to be seen DropDownList selectively, but at the same time I want to fill in the DropDownList for all the other data in the city and town table. For example: When I registered I chose Portland as city and I chose Hood River as town. And I want these two to come as an selected, but I want to list all other towns and cities in same dropdown.

This is my where I took the city and town information in the user table:

```
private void GetUserCityAndTown()
{
    if(Session["userid"] != null)
    {
        DataRow dr = function.GetDataRow("SELECT city.name, town.name FROM kullanici LEFT JOIN city on city.city_no = user.city LEFT JOIN town on town.town_no = user.town WHERE userid=" + Session["userid"].ToString());
        if (dr != null)
        {
            DrpDwnLstCity.Text = dr[0].ToString();
            DrpDwnLstTown.Text = dr[1].ToString();
        }
}
```

And this is where I took all the city information from city table:

```
private void GetCity()
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aytasarimConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM city", conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        DrpDwnLstCity.DataSource = reader;
        DrpDwnLstCity.DataValueField = "city_no";
        DrpDwnLstCity.DataTextField = "name";
        DrpDwnLstCity.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        string message = "<script>alert('Error!');</script>";
        Response.Write(message);
    }
}
```

And this is where I took all the town information from the town table:

```
private void GetTown()
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aytasarimConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM town WHERE city_no='" + DrpDwnLstCity.SelectedValue + "'", conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        DrpDwnLstTown.DataSource = reader;
        DrpDwnLstTown.DataValueField = "town_no";
        DrpDwnLstTown.DataTextField = "name";
        DrpDwnLstTown.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        string message = "<script>alert('Error!');</script>";
        Response.Write(message);
    }
}
```

Where do i make mistakes?

Comment: what is the order of invocation all of these functions?

Comment: Hocam merhabalar. Biraz geç cevap veriyorum ama çağrılma sıraları sayfanın page load kısmında şu şekilde: GetUserCityAndTown(), GetCity(), GetTown().

Comment: Yapmak istediğim şeyi İngilizce olarak tam açıklayabilmiş miyim bilmiyorum fakat tekrar anlatmam gerekirse. Kullanıcı kayıt formunda kullanıcının il ve ilçe bilgisini kullanıcı tablosuna kaydediyorum (il ve ilçe için 2 farklı tablom var). Daha sonra kullanıcı profilini düzenlemeye girdiğinde kayıt sırasında seçmiş olduğu il ve ilçenin DropDownList'te seçili olarak gelmesini, bunun yanında diğer tüm şehirleri ve ilçeleri yine bu DropDownList'e doldurmak istiyorum ki kullanıcı rahatça seçimini değiştirip güncelleme yapabilsin diye.